# XPATH 1.0 : match not empty elements

Tags: xpath

I need to match elements that contain neither `PCDATA` nor child elements.

I tried this:

```
.//myelem[count(nodes())=0]
```

but `nodes()` is unknown in XPATH 1.0.

What is the most concise way that you know of to do this in XPATH 1.0 ?

Comment: I suggest reducing the question tags to "xpath" only. The others aren't really helpful. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You were close - it is `node()`, not `nodes()`:

```
.//myelem[count(node()) = 0]
```

or, more idiomatically:

```
.//myelem[not(node())]
```