# Filter out Empty elements from Array - XPATH

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, xpath

***<sub>Context:</sub>***

I'm trying to `Filter` out `Empty` values from an array. I know we can loop an array to `Redim Preserve` but figured there could be a way to incorporate the `Filter` function. However, since `Filter` treats all elements in an `Array` as `String` data types, there is no such thing as `arr = Filter(arr, Empty, False)` which I have tried in many forms.

This brought me to `WorksheetFuntion.FilterXML` however, I have little to none experience in XPATH and am clearly doing something wrong missing the concept of elements and nodes. I'm aware that Excel works on XPATH 1.0 and therefor I was browsing for a way to "filter" out empty elements and came accross [[not(node())]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1914085/9758194). However implementing this returned an `Error 1004` on retrieving `arr1`

---

***<sub>Sample:</sub>***

```
Sub Test()

Dim arr0 As Variant, arr1 As Variant, arr2 As Variant

arr0 = Array("A", "A", Empty, "A")
arr1 = WorksheetFunction.FilterXML("<t><s>" & Join(arr0, "</s><s>") & "</s></t>", "//s[not(node())]")
arr2 = WorksheetFunction.FilterXML("<t><s>" & Join(arr0, "</s><s>") & "</s></t>", "//s[string-length(text()) > 0]")

End Sub
```

---

***<sub>Question:</sub>***

To circumvent the issue my second option was to check the length of the strings which in this case did work and returned an array without empty elements.

Can someone enlighten me on how to improve the `[not(node())]` syntax to make it work.
Some explaination on **why** the current code doesn't work would also be highly appreciated.

Comment: Seems like the "loop and fill another array" approach would be more robust/predicatable?

Comment: @TimWilliams it would be, I do acknowledge that (there are restrictions to the HTML length I believe). However, without benchmarking anything (though knowing `Redim Preserve` is slow) I would like to know/understand how to make this `XPATH` work which is the subject of this question.

Comment: Understood - though you only need to ReDim once  - at the end - if you start with a second array the same size as your input array.

Comment: The XPath `"//s[string-length(text()) > 0]"` selects `s` elements which have a non-empty first text child node. The XPath `//s[not(node())]` selects `s` elements which don't have any child node. I have no idea how Excel uses XPath and what the error `Error 1004` is meant to tell. Constructing XML by string concatenation/joining is going to fail once you have e.g. an ampersand or less than sign in any of the array item strings so if you want to rely on XPath it would be better to use DOM or XmlWriter to build the XML first. That's just general advice not related to that particular XPath problem

Comment: @Added a XPath approach to your `FilterXML` question yesterday :) @JvdV

Comment: @T.M. thanks a bunch, I appreciate it.

Comment: @JvdV FYI you might be interested in an approach assigning defined XML **file** contents (URL *or* local) directly via `FilterXML` to an array, too - c.f. [XPath evaluation in VBA Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24497394/xpath-evaluation-in-vba-excel/60270498#60270498)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Improve `[Not(node())]` syntax**

Simply use `//s[not(.='')]`, i.e.

```
arr1 = WorksheetFunction.FilterXML("<t><s>" & Join(arr0, "</s><s>") & "</s></t>", "//s[not(.='')]")
```

where `.` refers to the node content itself, compared with an empty string and negated :-)